# how to initialize viewmodel in activity using dagger?

Tags: android

I'm dev-ing activity using dagger. In my fragment, I can use this code as below. but when I use this code in activity, I cannot use this code.

```
 private val viewModel by viewModels<NoticeViewModel> { viewModelFactory }
```

As result I can't initialize viewmodel. how can I initialize activity using dagger?

*fragment*

```
class NoticeFragment : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val viewModel by viewModels<NoticeViewModel> { viewModelFactory }

    private lateinit var viewDataBinding: FragmentNoticeBinding

    private var notice = ""

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notice, container, false)
        viewDataBinding = FragmentNoticeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        return view
    }


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner
        init()
        viewModel.getNotice()
    }

    private fun init(){
        viewModel.notice.observe(this, Observer{
            noticeMain.text = it

        })
    }

}
```

*activity*

```
class ScheduleDialog : DaggerActivity() {


    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val viewModel by viewModels<ScheduleDialogViewModel> { viewModelFactory }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule_dialog)
        //viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView( this,R.layout.activity_schedule_dialog)

        viewModel.getScheduleById(5)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   MyComponent component = DaggerMyComponent.builder().build();
   component.inject(this);
```

For dependency injection you should have the following code, also in the component code should be

```
   void inject(YourActivity activity);
```